# Spring Boot endpoint for downloading File automatically

Tags: file, spring-boot

I want to make a Spring Boot endpoint for downloading file. I Have tried this things but the file does not download automatically... I get only file content in the body...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> getFile(@RequestParam(name = "start") String start)  {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new FileSystemResource(myService.makeFile(start)),
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Another one that I have tried is this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public String download(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(name = "start") String start)
         {
    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(myService.makeFile(start));
    return IOUtils.toString(fr);
}
```

I have read that MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE will force it to download but nothing happened in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, you just need to set one response header `Content-Disposition` to `attachment; filename=YOUR_FILE_NAME`.

Try This:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public FileSystemResource getFile(@RequestParam(name = "start") String start, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "YOUR_FILE_NAME");
    return new FileSystemResource(myService.makeFile(start));
}
```